# Adjust listview along with expandable edittext in chat app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

In my chat application I have a layout with a listview (a chat between two users) and an edittext input for writing a new message for the same conversation. 
The first problem happens when a user clicks on input - a soft keyboard pops up but the listview remains at the same position as before, instead of jumping up along with an edittext input and keeping the same interval between.
[image: default view + keyboard up]

The second problem is when I dismiss keyboard and return to the default state with a large number of lines, the listview again remains at the same position and the edittext overlaps it.
[image]

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<include
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    layout="@layout/actionbar_layout" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lsvMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@color/_transperant"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp">
</ListView>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/txtMsgLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/_transperant">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtMsg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/btn_ask_hint"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:textColor="@color/_white"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </EditText>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/message_spinner_layout"
        style="@style/layout_fill_width"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/message_lng_spinner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_setting"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/message_lng_spinner"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        style="@style/submit_button_style"
        android:text="@string/btnSend"
        android:background="@drawable/submit_button"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to fix it programmatically and count the high of edittext layout to move listview accordingly but it didn't work.

```
final View activityRootView = 
((ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
final View msgLayout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.txtMsgLayout);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener
(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
      Rect r = new Rect();
      activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
      int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
          if (heightDiff > 100) {
                scrollMyListViewToBottom();
          } else {
              int heighListview = msgLayout.getHeight();
              ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)     
              lsvMessage.getLayoutParams();
              params.setMargins(0,50,0,heighListview);
              lsvMessage.setLayoutParams(params);
          }
        }
    });
```

Can I fix it with a properly marked up layout or code behind?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I have tried all answers in the stackoverflow, but not have any final solution.

I found solution from google native message app:
[ComposeMessageActivity layout](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/res/layout/compose_message_activity.xml)

[ComposeMessageActivity](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/src/com/android/mms/ui/ComposeMessageActivity.java) here have a method: "**smoothScrollToEnd**"

and there are have a MessageListView.java class for detect onSizeChanged.